# how to require only first 6 numbers from body, nodejs

Tags: node.js

my second question , currently its sending the entire number, while the api requires just the first six, how do i take only the first six, sorry am really new to node but liking it

```js
unirest.get(`https://bins.payout.com/api/v1/bins/${req.body.card_number}`).end((resp) => {
            if(resp.body === undefined) return res.json({});
            if(resp.body.err) console.log(resp.body.err);
            res.json(resp.body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
req.body.card_number
```

you can use:

```
req.body.card_number.slice(0,6)
```

if `card_number` is a string, or:

```
req.body.card_number.toString().slice(0,6)
```

if `card_number` is a number.

Comment: Respect @rsp. worked like a charm .. thanks so much, how to mark this as answered ?

Comment: @catecho It's already marked as answered. I'm glad I could help.